# Assets controller returning a 404 for assets in a folder different than '/public'

Tags: playframework-2.3

I have a '/ui' folder and I would like to have the Assets controller looking for assets there instead of '/public'. I added this line to my routes file:

```
GET     /ui               controllers.Assets.at(path="/ui", file="index.html")
GET     /ui/*file         controllers.Assets.at(path="/ui", file)
```

However it doesn't work. Any suggestions about how I can fix this?

I'm using playing 2.3.8.

Comment: According to the documentation : "By convention public assets are stored in the public folder of your application. This folder can be organized the way that you prefer."
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets. I think the word "convention" is important...

Comment: If you can't change the path variable, it is pointless to have to specify it on the routes file.

Comment: It's more a `build` problem that does not know that it has to copy your `ui` folder in the `target/web` folder.